# Rails: how to use "returning id" (last inserted id in this code)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have read about curval, lastval and the best one, returning id, but all the examples I have seen were written in plain sql (insert ...)

However, I am using active record here in my controller. The thing is I have a New Form to add articles with the File Upload field, but I also want to add pictures, which are in other table, so since the Pictures table has a Foreign Key pointing to Articles table, I need that last ID to do the insertion in my pictures table.

Here is the method in the Articles Controller

```
def create
      @article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)
    if @article.save
      flash[:success] = "Article created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'articles/new'
 end
```

Picture Model:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
 mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader

end
```

And the Article Model has this

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :pictures
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, allow_destroy: true
```

plus the validations

Update:

I have read that in this case, by writing Article.id you get the id of the last inserted row in the Articles table, yet, the second part of the question still remains, how do you use that to add it to the Save command to the Pictures table.

So, how do you go about that? simply writing "returning id below the line
if @article.save  ?
(this is the kind of problems that arise when abandoning clear sql and having to write Active Record, I am lost with it. Then it is also unclear so far how to add that returning id to the Save method in the Pictures.
UPDATE 2:

I am including the strong parameters

```
def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:country, :region, :town, :street, :company, :title, :content, :picture)
    end
```

The Top of the form

```
<%= form_for(@article, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
```

MY UPDATE:

The answer was still not correct as first there was a small bug in the fields_for in the Form which caused the picture not to be sent to the controller.

But once someone helped me with that, still there was a problem, which was that the picture simply would not get saved.

I looked in the Log and I could read: Unpermitted parameter picture. This was saying that the strong parameters private method was not correct when it came to the Pictures table. That is, this was not correct:

```
params.require(:article).permit(:country, :region, :town, :street, :company, :title, :content, :picture)
```

but the attribute picture had to be broken down in its parts like this:

```
def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:country, :region, :town, :street, :company, :title, :content, pictures_attributes: [:id, :article_id, :picture])
    end
```

And this finally solved it, but for someone who has been teaching Rails himself for two weeks, it was a challenge, despite having read most of the Guides and even the Hartl book. This was, to me, a bit advanced.

Comment: I went ahead and removed my helpful comment based on your somewhat rude response. Good luck.

Comment: Using `save!` is often a less messy alternative. Then you can rescue `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` and display errors.

Comment: I know that the bang displays errors, but the question is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating the `article`, you don't need to manually assign the `article_id` to the `picture` object.

With all the models, associations in place and using the appropriate form helpers, you can let `rails` handle that for you.

Assuming you have a `title` field on the `articles` tables, you could use the following form, which when submitted, will setup both `article` and `pictures` for that `article`.

```
<%= form_for @article, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= fields_for :pictures do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.file_field :picture %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You also need to setup/build these `pictures` in your `new` action of the `ArticlesController` as follows:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @article = current_user.articles.build
    @article.pictures.build
  end
end
```

And let `rails` know that you want to accept `picture` arguments from the `article` model as follows:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :pictures
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures
end
```

Refer to [FormHelpers#fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) for more info.

Comment: I appreciate enormously the help and I know I am very close as I understand what u all say. It is the part of the Form that Chong says, I dont know how to include that extra :pictures and |ff| that he mentions.

Comment: Check the sample form that was included in the answer

Comment: Deep thanks to everybody. I have learned a lot with this one, since, for a beginner it was quite unseen. Chong also deserves the correct answer. There should be a system where it is possible to give same points to everybody.

Comment: Dharam. As I pasted this: <% fields_for :pictures do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.file_field :picture %>
  <% end %>
The file Upload disappeared. Are u sure it is the correct code?

Comment: It should be `<%= fields_for :pictures do |ff| %> <%= ff.file_field :picture %> <% end %>`. I updated the code in the answer. Besides, review the link included for `FormHelpers#fields_for` for more info.

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding pictures directly in the article form, you should build the pictures as so.

```
@article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)
@article.pictures.build
```

and in your `models/article.rb` add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures`. so that you are able to add `f.form_for :pictures do |ff|` like so. Remember to add the attributes into the strong params as well.